# Save checkbox value to database in codeiniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I can't seem to save the checkbox values to database,is their something iam missing in the code given below.Help me with a solution,as in using the code given below i seem to only save a particular checkbox value instead of every checkbox value checked.

view

```
 Subject :
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2" value="English">English
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2" value="Science">Science
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2" value="Maths">Maths
```

controller

```
  $data['subject'] = $this->input->post('s2');
```

model

```
  $this->db->insert('student', $data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers but i got the solutions...

**controller**

```
    $array = $this->input->post('s2');
    $data['subject'] = implode(',',$array);
    $this->student_model->saveForm($data);
```

**view**

Subject :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2[]" value="English">English
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2[]" value="Science">Science
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2[]" value="Maths">Maths
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2[]" value="English">English
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2[]" value="Science">Science
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2[]" value="Maths">Maths
```

Make them group and take the value in controller like this

```
$data['course'] = $this->input->post('s2');
```

Comment: srry that was my mistake
    $data['subject'] = $this->input->post('s2');

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...`s2=>s2[]`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2[]" value="English">English
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2[]" value="Science">Science
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="s2[]" value="Maths">Maths
```

Controller

```
if(!empty($this->input->post('s2')) {
    $data['course'] = $this->input->post('s2');

    foreach($data['course'] as $value)
    {
        echo 'Checked: '.$value;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you are getting if you print the array `print_r($data['course']);`

Comment: then you are not getting the form values, troubleshoot it.

Comment: No that can't be,as one value gets saved using the code i had given above so its got to be something else...

Answer (score 0):

maybe just a typo, but you are referencing `...post('s1')` but all your checkboxes have name `s2` also, remember that with input fields sharing the same name, an array is created on the server side: so the structure would look a little like this:

```
$_POST => array(
  s2 => array(
    "English",
    "...",
  )
  ...
)
```

also, remember that a checkbox must be checked for its value to be submitted to the server

Comment: it was my mistake,i changed it

Answer (score 0):

`$this->input->post` read value from name not from id.

so your code should be like this

```
$data['course'] = $this->input->post('s2');
```

Comment: it was my mistake,i changed it

Answer (score 0):

To submit an input group with same name, you have to do it with `name="s2[]"`. The `[]` mean to submit the inputs in an array form.

So in php, you will have `$_POST['s2'][0]` as the first checked subject following the sequence and so on, i.e. `$_POST['s2'][0]` as English, `$_POST['s2'][1]` as Science AND `$_POST['s2'][2]` as Maths, if all inputs are checked.

In addition, I'm not quite sure about what does the "s1" do in `$data['course'] = $this->input->post('s1');`, aren't you suppose to do actions with "s2"?

Hope this can help

Comment: it was my mistake,i changed it